# C# - How can I make a 'chance of success' method

Tags: c#

I've been learning c# and I want to start an experimental console application project of an American Football Simulator. It is vital for this project to have chances.

> Example: there's a 20% chance the kicker will succeed in a field goal kick over 45 yards.

I've looked around on here and noticed people using randoms, but is that really the most efficient way to go about doing this?

```
Random chance = new Random(1, 100);
If (Yards > 45)
{
    If (chance <= 20)
    {
        // Field goal success
    }
    else
    {
        // Field goal fail
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: If you want random chances, `Random` is what you need.

Comment: `new Random` is not.  Create it just once.  And learn how to use its Next() method.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Just do this:

```
private Random _rnd = new Random();
public bool RandomSuccess(double probability)
{
    return _rnd.NextDouble() < probability;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
if (Yards > 45)
{
    if (RandomSuccess(0.2))
    {
        // Field goal success
    }
    else
    {
        // Field goal fail
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot pass a double to a method that expects a boolean.

Comment: I'm getting an error that the operator cannot be applied to operands of type double and bool

Comment: @Donavon maybe you should *understand* the answer and then fix the trivial mistake that has been made.

Comment: @usr, people simply downvote without understanding a solution. It is normal to quote on mistakes.

Comment: @Ahelo - Thanks for the fix.